# Or or or or or... displayed when searching for or clicking on a wildcard favourite tag in the new navigation

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-nav

[image: Example]

This happens when clicking on a wildcard link from my Favourite Tags list in the sidebar. It goes away if I refresh the page and doesn't happen at all if I visit the page through the URL it generates.

It also happens when searching. This is what happens when searching for `[status-*]` here on Meta SE:

[image: Example 2]

Weirdly on Stack Overflow the ORs are placed at the end and here on Meta SE the ORs are placed at the beginning. It updates the search box text to include the ORs too, so this placement isn't caused by styling. **Edit**: in fact, it appears to alphabetically sort the ORs alongside the tags!

Comment: Hah! This made my day . . .

Comment: Related report on [MSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300270/wildcard-tag-results-in-or-or-or)

Comment: Nice! Consider it in-progress

Comment: @JamesDonnelly - there's a reason for the positioning of the 'or's - they're alphabetical. '`o`' is after the '`c`' in `css` but before '`s`' in `status`

Comment: Someone should send the screencap in to Daily WTF's "Error'd" segment. :)